# CSS to style some text after a special character has occurred?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have accomplished:

[image]

using Javascript.

But for some reasons, I need to have a pure CSS solution instead? Is that possible?

JS code:

```
var titles=document.getElementsByClassName(\"title\");
    for(var i=0;i<titles.length;i++){
    var blueFoo = titles[i].innerHTML.split(\":\")[0];
                var text = titles[i].innerHTML;
                var newHTML = text.replace(blueFoo,'<span style = \"color:rgb(67, 116, 159)\">' + blueFoo + '</span>');
                titles[i].innerHTML = newHTML;
    }
```

Comment: No. You cannot evaluate text strings with CSS.

Comment: You need to clarify your question. I see @isherwood interpretation but I also see Kalel's interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can do it partialy. Basically you have to do the java script to break up the text you want styled. (This is also assuming you can't just add the span directly to html instead of using javascript).

```
<style>
.myStyle{ color:rgb(67, 116, 159); }
</style>
<script>
var titles=document.getElementsByClassName(\"title\");
    for(var i=0;i<titles.length;i++){
    var blueFoo = titles[i].innerHTML.split(\":\")[0];
                var text = titles[i].innerHTML;
                var newHTML = text.replace(blueFoo,'<span class=\"myStyle\">' + blueFoo + '</span>');
                titles[i].innerHTML = newHTML;
    }    
</script>
```

Comment: OP asked for a CSS solution.

Comment: OP asked for solution that is not possible with just CSS. So I gave a partial one.

Comment: I think before we can continue to down vote this answer, we should have the op clarify the question. This would have been my answer given my interpretation of the question.